# How to remove duplicate values in window function usage?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to run the below code to replicate sum of order volume across all rows. I am trying to do it for last 2 weeks, which implies that I should get 14 rows of data. However, I am getting a lot of duplicates and GROUP BY wouldn't work. Could someone please help me here? Thanks!

```
SELECT
TO_CHAR(DATE_TRUNC('week',START_OF_PERIOD_LOCAL),'YYYY-MM-DD') AS WEEK,
TO_CHAR(START_OF_PERIOD_LOCAL , 'DY') AS DAY_OF_WEEK,
sum(ORDERS_DELIVERED) over () as total_orders
FROM p
WHERE
CITY_NAME='Hong Kong' AND
DATEDIFF('DAY',DATE_TRUNC('DAY',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),DATE_TRUNC('DAY',START_OF_PERIOD_LOCAL)) BETWEEN -14 AND 0
GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY 1
```

[sample results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Us88Q.png)

[Ideal Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCNZS.png)

Comment: Sample data and desired results please.

Comment: Added sample and desired results

Answer (score 0):

To remove duplicates, you need to use distinct. Try the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
TO_CHAR(DATE_TRUNC('week',START_OF_PERIOD_LOCAL),'YYYY-MM-DD') AS WEEK,
TO_CHAR(START_OF_PERIOD_LOCAL , 'DY') AS DAY_OF_WEEK,
sum(ORDERS_DELIVERED) over () as total_orders
FROM p
WHERE
CITY_NAME='Hong Kong' AND
DATEDIFF('DAY',DATE_TRUNC('DAY',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),DATE_TRUNC('DAY',START_OF_PERIOD_LOCAL)) BETWEEN -14 AND 0
GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: Why must one use distinct?  One could also use a CTE, surely?

Answer (score 0):

So with this CTE providing fake data:

```
WITH data(start_of_period_local, orders_delivered, city_name) AS (
    SELECT column1::date, column2, column3 FROM VALUES
    ('2022-01-27', 100, 'Hong Kong'),
    ('2022-01-27', 101, 'Hong Kong'),
    ('2022-01-26', 200, 'Hong Kong'),
    ('2022-01-26', 202, 'Hong Kong'),
    ('2022-01-18', 300, 'Hong Kong'),
    ('2022-01-18', 303, 'Hong Kong'),
    ('2022-01-17', 400, 'Hong Kong'),
    ('2022-01-01', 500, 'Hong Kong')  
)
```

We can reproduce your problem by swapping `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` with `to_date('2022-01-27','YYYY-MM-DD')` just so this works in the future.

```
WITH data(start_of_period_local, orders_delivered, city_name) AS (
    SELECT column1::date, column2, column3 FROM VALUES
    ('2022-01-27', 100, 'Hong Kong'),
    ('2022-01-27', 101, 'Hong Kong'),
    ('2022-01-26', 200, 'Hong Kong'),
    ('2022-01-26', 202, 'Hong Kong'),
    ('2022-01-18', 300, 'Hong Kong'),
    ('2022-01-18', 303, 'Hong Kong'),
    ('2022-01-17', 400, 'Hong Kong'),
    ('2022-01-01', 500, 'Hong Kong')  
)    
SELECT
    TO_CHAR(DATE_TRUNC('week', start_of_period_local),'YYYY-MM-DD') AS week,
    TO_CHAR(start_of_period_local, 'DY') AS day_of_week,
    SUM(orders_delivered) over () total_orders
FROM data
WHERE city_name = 'Hong Kong' 
    AND DATEDIFF('DAY', DATE_TRUNC('DAY', to_date('2022-01-27','YYYY-MM-DD')),DATE_TRUNC('DAY',start_of_period_local)) BETWEEN -14 AND 0
--GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY 1
```

gives:

| WEEK | DAY_OF_WEEK | TOTAL_ORDERS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-17 | Tue | 1,606 |
| 2022-01-17 | Tue | 1,606 |
| 2022-01-17 | Mon | 1,606 |
| 2022-01-24 | Thu | 1,606 |
| 2022-01-24 | Thu | 1,606 |
| 2022-01-24 | Wed | 1,606 |
| 2022-01-24 | Wed | 1,606 |

So one way is the DISTINCT that Niharika offers, another is to group on the days (aka drop the `over()`, and add an extra dependent aggregate to access the totals, which assume you want both.

```
SELECT
    TO_CHAR(DATE_TRUNC('week', start_of_period_local),'YYYY-MM-DD') AS week,
    TO_CHAR(start_of_period_local, 'DY') AS day_of_week,
    SUM(orders_delivered) AS daily_orders,
    SUM(total_orders) over () AS total_orders 
FROM data
WHERE city_name = 'Hong Kong' 
    AND DATEDIFF('DAY', DATE_TRUNC('DAY', to_date('2022-01-27','YYYY-MM-DD')),DATE_TRUNC('DAY',start_of_period_local)) BETWEEN -14 AND 0
GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY 1
```

which does give you a column that here you didn't ask for

| WEEK | DAY_OF_WEEK | DAILY_ORDERS | TOTAL_ORDERS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-17 | Tue | 603 | 1,606 |
| 2022-01-17 | Mon | 400 | 1,606 |
| 2022-01-24 | Thu | 201 | 1,606 |
| 2022-01-24 | Wed | 402 | 1,606 |

which you can drop and inline the composite like:

```
SELECT
    TO_CHAR(DATE_TRUNC('week', start_of_period_local),'YYYY-MM-DD') AS week,
    TO_CHAR(start_of_period_local, 'DY') AS day_of_week,
    SUM(SUM(orders_delivered)) over () AS total_orders 
FROM data
WHERE city_name = 'Hong Kong' 
    AND DATEDIFF('DAY', DATE_TRUNC('DAY', to_date('2022-01-27','YYYY-MM-DD')),DATE_TRUNC('DAY',start_of_period_local)) BETWEEN -14 AND 0
GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY 1
```

which gives:

| WEEK | DAY_OF_WEEK | TOTAL_ORDERS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-17 | Tue | 1,606 |
| 2022-01-17 | Mon | 1,606 |
| 2022-01-24 | Thu | 1,606 |
| 2022-01-24 | Wed | 1,606 |